# Calling a user-defined function located in "postgres.c" in postgreSQL using a GUI defined by netbeans

Tags: java, c, postgresql, global-variables, postgresql-8.4

I' trying to add 3 user_defined function to the PostgreSQL-8.4.15. Here are 3 functions:

(1) `start_create_profile();`

(2) `make_profile();`

(3) `check_anomaly();`

All of them are written in file "test.c" located in src/backend/tcop. I want to call (1) and (3) from the middle of `exec_simple_query()`. `exec_simple_query()` is PostgreSQL function that is written in "postgres.c" located in src/backend/tcop. I want to call (2) directly through my GUI.

here is the my code written in "test.c" :

```
#include "postgres.h"

#ifndef PROGPROFILE_H_
#define PROGPROFILE_H_

/* interfaces */
extern void start_create_profile(List *querytree_list);
extern void create_profile();
extern void check_anomaly(List *querytree_list);

#endif /* Test ProgProf */


void start_create_profile(List *querytree_list){

    ListCell *l;
    ListCell *tl;
    FILE *f;

    //if the file exist just open and write
    //else create and write
    f = fopen ("QueryParsed.txt", "a+");

    Query *query_idr = (Query *)linitial(querytree_list);

    // CMD_SELECT=0 CMD_INSERT=1 CMD_UPDATE=2
    switch (query_idr->commandType)
    {
        case CMD_SELECT:
            fputs("CMD_SELECT, ", f);
        break;

        case CMD_INSERT:
            fputs("CMD_INSERT, ", f);
            break;

        case CMD_UPDATE:
            fputs("CMD_UPDATE, ", f);
        break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    //to have the ID of the table
    foreach(l, query_idr->rtable){
        Oid tab_idT = ((RangeTblEntry *) lfirst(l)) ->relid;
        //char temp1[10];
        char *tab_idTConverted = itoa(tab_idT);
        /* This is not a table */
        if (tab_idT == 0)
            continue;

        fputs(" tab_id:  , ", f);
        fputs(tab_idTConverted, f);

    }

    //to have the name of the targer list
    foreach(tl, query_idr->targetList){
        TargetEntry *tle = (TargetEntry *) lfirst(tl);
        Oid tab_id = tle->resorigtbl;
        int tab_idCast=(int)tab_id;
        //char temp[10];
        char *tab_idConverted = itoa(tab_idCast);
        char *resname=tle->resname;

        fputs("Name of column:  ", f);
        fputs(resname, f);
        fputs(" ID:  ", f);
        fputs(tab_idConverted, f);
        fputs("\n", f);
    }

    //close the file that we write
    fputs("$", f);
    fclose (f);
}


void create_profile(){

}

void check_anomaly(List *querytree_list){

}
```

Now I've created a very simple GUI including 3 buttons(by netbeans in java). Button1, button2, button3 corresponding by order to `start_create_profile()`, make_profile, `check_anomaly()`.

I want to use a global variable(Let's consider "button" that can be set to 3 different values like 0, 1, 2. I want that whenever I push the button1 or button3 the global variable become set to 1 or 2 in order to use "if" that I've written in `exec_simple_query()`. here is "if"

```
//initially button=0;
//inside exec_simple_query

if(button==1) start_create_profile();
if(button==2) check_anomaly;
```

and whenever I push the button2, the function(2) has to be called directly.
Any idea how do I have to set that variable to make me able choosing one of those 3 function using my GUI?? How do I have to call the function(2) directly through my GUI??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems here.

### You can't call just any C function from SQL

First, you can't just call arbitrary functions from SQL, you must use PostgreSQL's C extension APIs and macros; look at the existing implementations of SQL-callable functions in the sources for examples.

### You usually don't have to modify the core code, extensions are often sufficient

Second, if you want to add functions to the core PostgreSQL, you must add them to `src/include/catalog/pg_proc.h` so they're defined during `initdb`.

It's much better, however, to use the proper extension loading facilities:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-c.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-pgxs.html

This way you can `LOAD` an extension module, `CREATE FUNCTION` the C functions as per the docs, and call them from SQL.

In your specific case it looks like you *do* need to modify the core codebase, but this is quite unusual, so I'm preserving this advice for others.

### A C function in the PostgreSQL backend cannot be called "directly" from a GUI

You have a Java Swing GUI and you envision somehow calling a C function in a different process, possibly even on a different host, from it.

This won't work for a bunch of reasons, including:

- Java can't directly call C functions without glue code like `JNI` or `JNA`.
- It is not possible to call a C function in a different process directly; you must instead use inter-process communication (shared memory, pipes, sockets, shared files, etc) to exchange information
- While you could embed a Java interpreter in the Pg backend and call the C function via JNI kind-of-directly, you *really* don't want to try to display a Swing GUI directly from inside a Pg backend.

What you need is a multi-stage process:

- Collect the data you wish to capture in the PostgreSQL backend. If you intend to access it from the same connection that it's created in you can use an ordinary `palloc`'d buffer. Otherwise you will need to allocate a buffer out of shared memory or exchange data using the file system.
- Access that data from a C function that has been created with an SQL-callable interface as per PostgreSQL's C extension function documentation (above)
- Use a PostgreSQL connection to transfer the data from your SQL-callable interface function to your Java application. Decode it in your application and display it as desired.

Alternately:

- Require that your Java program, or an agent for it, run on the same system as the PostgreSQL server and have the agent write files in a location writable to Pg and readable by your program.
- Read the files using your program or its agent and process them for display

You could even have Pg write to a socket your program is listening on, but I don't recommend this as a stall in your program would cause performance problems in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help. Let me ask my question from another aspect. I don't want to create SQL function.What I'm doing is making a c-function in postgres(my-function) and call it from exec_simple_query. as I understood, First of all I need to compile and link the file containing the c-code(my-function) with PostgreSQL. Then I need to call my-function using a GUI(I call my-function from the middle of exec_simple_query code). Please let me know if I'm understanding wrong. Sorry if my question seems amateur.I'm very new with postgreSQL and and I need to do it as soon as possible.

Comment: exec_simple_query is a Postgresql function in postgres.c

Comment: @Amir.h Do you intend your function to be *callable from SQL*? Do you want to be able to write `SELECT my_function()`? Or is it intended for use as a hook function where you can do something whenever an SQL statement is run?

Comment: here is my modified question with more detail. I hope it is explained well enough. Thank you for helping me

Comment: @Amir.h Amended, hope this helps. You've tackled a much bigger job than you may have realised.

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete detailed answer. It's about a week that I'm working on multi stage process but as you said before, it's a much bigger job than I may have realised. So I started working on your alternative approach. I have my Java program run on the same system as the PostgreSQL server and I'm trying to figure out how to use glue code but I didn't get the point about how to connect my GUI to the C function in this approach.I know this is my lack of knowledge in this field but I was wondering if you can help me with this approach with more detail.Thank you very much

Comment: @Amir.h Sorry, I've just got a bit too much going on and can't really write a detailed tutorial at this time. You really need C->Java IPC (inter-process communication) if you're running the data sender and data collector on the same machine. You can use unix sockets, tcp sockets, write files to directories, all sorts of approaches.

Comment: I understand and I appreciate you help. You mentioned IPC that is used for exchange data among multiple treads but my GUI is not supposed to exchange any data with PostgreSQL.It just has to call a user_defined_function() in Pg. Do you still believe I need to use IPC?

Comment: @Amir.h Well, you either need to use your own IPC, or expose that function at the SQL level and call it from a regular PostgreSQL connection. If it's viable to expose it from SQL that's what I'd do, it just sounded from your previous comments like you didn't consider that to be an option.