# Extending postgresql code

Tags: c, eclipse, function, postgresql, development-environment

Following on from [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019257/calling-a-user-defined-function-located-in-postgres-c-in-postgresql-using-a-gu): 
In the PostgreSQL source code there is a file called `postgres.c` in `src/backend/tcop`. Inside there is a function called `exec_simple_query()`. I want add a line that calls `start_create_profile()` that is in another file called `test.c` in the same folder as `postgres.c` .

I'm working with eclipse on linux (kubuntu/ubuntu). I followed this tutorial to creating the environment http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Eclipse

This is test.c:

```
#include "postgres.h"

#ifndef PROGPROFILE_H_
#define PROGPROFILE_H_

/* interfaces */
extern void start_create_profile(List *querytree_list);
extern void create_profile();
extern void check_anomaly(List *querytree_list);

#endif /* Test ProgProf */


void start_create_profile(List *querytree_list){

    ListCell *l;
    ListCell *tl;
    FILE *f;

    //if the file exist just open and write
    //else create and write
    f = fopen ("QueryParsed.txt", "a+");

    Query *query_idr = (Query *)linitial(querytree_list);

    // CMD_SELECT=0 CMD_INSERT=1 CMD_UPDATE=2
    switch (query_idr->commandType)
    {
        case CMD_SELECT:
            fputs("CMD_SELECT, ", f);
        break;

        case CMD_INSERT:
            fputs("CMD_INSERT, ", f);
            break;

        case CMD_UPDATE:
            fputs("CMD_UPDATE, ", f);
        break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    //to have the ID of the table
    foreach(l, query_idr->rtable){
        Oid tab_idT = ((RangeTblEntry *) lfirst(l)) ->relid;
        //char temp1[10];
        char *tab_idTConverted = itoa(tab_idT);
        /* This is not a table */
        if (tab_idT == 0)
            continue;

        fputs(" tab_id:  , ", f);
        fputs(tab_idTConverted, f);

    }

    //to have the name of the targer list
    foreach(tl, query_idr->targetList){
        TargetEntry *tle = (TargetEntry *) lfirst(tl);
        Oid tab_id = tle->resorigtbl;
        int tab_idCast=(int)tab_id;
        //char temp[10];
        char *tab_idConverted = itoa(tab_idCast);
        char *resname=tle->resname;

        fputs("Name of column:  ", f);
        fputs(resname, f);
        fputs(" ID:  ", f);
        fputs(tab_idConverted, f);
        fputs("\n", f);
    }

    //close the file that we write
    fputs("$", f);
    fclose (f);
}


void create_profile(){

}

void check_anomaly(List *querytree_list){

}
```

But, when I click on build I get this error:

```
Description Path    Resource    Location    Type
make: *** [all] Error 2     pgsql       C/C++ Problem
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2      pgsql       C/C++ Problem
make[2]: *** [postgres] Error 1     pgsql       C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `start_create_profile'   /pgsql/src/backend/tcop postgres.c      C/C++ Problem
```

I Think the problem must related to modifying postgres source code. Any idea??

Thanks

Comment: How do you think exec_simple_query() should know how to find start_create_profile()?

Comment: Thanks for you time. I don't know how I have to link the test.c with postgreSQL. Linking them is exactly what I don't know

Comment: The function exec_simple_query() calls the function pgstat_report_activity(). When the compiler compiles postgres.c, how does it know how to find pgstat_report_activity()? (Hint: it doesn't guess.)

Comment: Background here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019257/calling-a-user-defined-function-located-in-postgres-c-in-postgresql-using-a-gu

Comment: @Amir.h Looks like you didn't actually link to your added file. Did you add it to the Makefile? It sounds like you're doing profiling / parse tree work; have you looked into PostgreSQL's existing integratoin with the Linux `perf` subsystem and/or OProfile?

Comment: @Amir.h ... or, looking at the code, are you really trying to add *auditing*?

Comment: @CraigRinger Thank you very much, I resolved that error by adding test.o to the Makefile. But I'm still have my problem that you mentioned above (Background here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019257/calling-a-user-defined-function-located-in-postgres-c-in-postgresql-using-a-gu). I mean calling my-function using using a GUI whenever I need it.

Comment: @Amir.h You will need to explain that in a LOT more detail. *What* GUI? PgAdmin-III? Call it *how*? To get what? You've omitted pretty much every useful detail. Describe the problem you are trying to solve, the desired result, and how you imagine you'll get from the problem to the desired result. Maybe update your earlier question?

Comment: @CraigRinger Sure. Now I'm going to update that question

Comment: @CraigRinger I've just updated my earlier question. I hope it is explained well enough. please let me know if you need any more detail. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem adding `test.o` in OBJECT the makefile in `src/backend/tcop`.

An istance can be

```
subdir = src/backend/tcop
top_builddir = ../../..
include $(top_builddir)/src/Makefile.global

OBJS= dest.o fastpath.o postgres.o pquery.o utility.o test.o

ifneq (,$(filter $(PORTNAME),cygwin win32))
override CPPFLAGS += -DWIN32_STACK_RLIMIT=$(WIN32_STACK_RLIMIT)
endif

include $(top_srcdir)/src/backend/common.mk
```